why when i run the cordova build android command i get the error cordova build failled?
I just discovered cordova and I was able to create my first application without any problem, my only concern now is to generate the .apk file to be able to install it on android devices, when trying to execute the command 'cordova build android' I come across this error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\le\Downloads\blender 2.8\Cordova\Percian\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 73

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 34.0.0.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 54s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\le\Downloads\blender 2.8\Cordova\Percian\platforms\android\tools\gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug

, can someone help me ?
I tried to watch some tutorials on YouTube but as I'm a beginner, I don't understand much.
